# how to avoid repeat value in query table

Tags: sql

3 table here

t1:

```
Id   a
1   100
1   600
2   800
```

t2:

```
Id    b
1    600
2    700
3    400
```

t3:

```
Id    c
2    400
3    800
4    100
```

below sql code run....

```
SELECT  t.id, t1.a, t2.b, t3.c
FROM (((select id 
        from t1
        union 
        select id
        from t2 
        union 
        select id 
        from t3 )  AS t
        LEFT JOIN t1 ON t.id = t1.id)
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t.Id = t2.Id)
 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t.Id = t3.Id;
```

got result and recode duplicate value like this

```
id   a      b     c
1   600     600  400
1   100     600  400
2   800     700 
3           400  800
4           100
```

but i want result avoid duplicate value below like this:

```
Id     a        b      c 
 1    100      600    400
 1    600       -      -
 2    800      700     -         
 3     -       400    800
 4     -        -     100
```

ples help.........

Comment: I see sample data, I see tried query, I see results AND expected results, but I don't see a question...

Comment: How to decide which id = 1 row to assign b and c values?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
WHERE t1.a <> t2.b
AND t1.a <> t3.c
AND t2.b <> t3.c
```